# Inverse of matrix in matlab with symbolic toolbox

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, matrix-inverse

I'm new in Matlab. How can I do calculate a inverse of a matrix with symbolic toolbox ? 
In my matrix there is a laplace variable "s".

Answer (score 0):

```
syms('s', 'x');                      % You declare the symbols `s' and `x' this way.
M = [exp(-s)*x 1; 0 exp(-s)*sin(x)]; % This is a sample matrix
M*inv(M)                             % inv() gives you the inverse
```